# Why is ${\partial^i}{\partial_i\phi}$ = ${\partial^i {\phi}}{\partial_i{\phi}}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, klein-gordon-equation

This notation can be found on page 254 of Victor Stenger's Comprehensible Cosmos and in David Tong's Lectures on QFT (Equation 2.4 http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/two.pdf), and in

EDIT: on page 254 of Stenger's Comprehensible Cosmos, the Lagrangian is written with a  ${\partial^i}{\partial_i\phi}$ instead of the usual ${\partial^i {\phi}}{\partial_i{\phi}}$ (that David Tong uses).

Why is ${\partial^i}{\partial_i\phi}$ = ${\partial^i {\phi}}{\partial_i{\phi}}$ in QFT ? This fact is used to calculate the Lagrange Equations of Motion (The Klein Gordon Equation) from the Lagrange Density for a Scalar Field.

This clearly isn't true for elementary functions like $y^2$ because ${\partial_y}{\partial_y\ ({y^2})}$ =/= $ {\partial_y {y^2}}{\partial_y{y^2}}$

Comment: It's not. That relation isn't even dimensionally correct. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I've seen the Lagrangian written ${\partial^i}{\partial_i\phi}$ or ${\partial^i {\phi}}{\partial_i{\phi}}$ or $({\partial^i {\phi}})^2$ Is this just a notational choice?

Comment: Where did you see that? One thing you can do is partial integration, but then you are missing at least one $\phi$. In deriving the Euler-Lagrange equations, you use partial integration.

Comment: I believe David Tong writes it this way in his Perimeter Lectures. Victor Stenger writes it this way on page 254 of his Comprehensible Cosmos Equation D120: $L=-\frac{1}{2}{\partial^i}{\partial_i\phi}+m^2 {\phi}^2$

Comment: Stenger also writes the K.G. Equation: ${\partial^i}{\partial_i\phi}+m^2 {\phi}^2 = 0$

Comment: I don't have David Tong's work handy, but all three expressions you list mean different things. I cannot even think of a non-trivial choice of $\phi$ where they could be equal. To get to from the second to the third you need to raise/lower an index with the metric, and I don't see any way to relate the first to the other two.

Comment: Now I believe it is just a weird notation. But it is something that has bothered me for awhile. I wasn't sure.

Comment: Here is David Tongs use of that notation. See Equation 2.4 of http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/two.pdf This is from http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html This course is excellent btw.

Comment: @BB1 Equations 2.4 and 1.13 of David's lectures are just two copies of the KG equation: $\partial^\mu\partial_\mu\phi+m^2\phi=0$. The scalar field lagrangian is equation 1.7 of the same lectures: $\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$. I don't see any place where he is equating $\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi$ and $\partial^\mu\partial_\mu\phi$. In section 1.1.1 he is just applying the ordinary process to get the equations of motion from the Lagrangian.

Comment: @mmc But isn't the KG Equation usually written ${\partial^i {\phi}}{\partial_i{\phi}}+m^2=0$? He writes it as you do.

Comment: @BB1 The KG _equation_ is always written as $(\partial^\mu\partial_\mu + m^2)\phi = 0$, $(\Box+m^2)\phi = 0$ or equivalent representations. See eq. 7 in [this lecture notes](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/129A/Dirac.pdf) or eq. 1.1.4 in Weinberg's QFT book. $\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi$ is the kinetic term of the KG Lagrangian.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have overlooked a letter. The kinetic term for the Klein-Gordon field is usually written as
$$ {\mathcal L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi. $$
However, the equations of motion (and the action, assuming vanishing of the fields at infinity) don't change if we add a total derivative (or divergence) to the Lagrangian. So we may subtract
$${\mathcal L}\to {\mathcal L}' = {\mathcal L} - \partial_\mu \left(\frac 12\phi \partial^\mu \phi\right). $$
Using the Leibniz rule (i.e. $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$), this modified Lagrangian is easily seen to be
$$ {\mathcal L}' = -\frac{1}{2} \phi \cdot \partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi $$
which is essentially what you wrote except that you omitted the factor of $-\phi$.

Comment: But David Tong and Victor Stenger both write it without the extra $\phi$. See the link I posted above to David Tong's Lectures.

Comment: OK, so David forgot the factor. Please send my best regards to David, I know him quite well. ... It's a somewhat usual, although not the most frequent, way of writing the Lagrangian in terms of the d'Alembertian (and it makes the derivation of the equations of motion somewhat more straightforward, by milliseconds), but the extra $\phi$ really but really can't be forgotten.

Comment: I'm surprised he forgot something. I thought he was using a weird notation. You're lucky to know him. His lectures were very entertaining. One of the best lecturers I've seen.

Comment: There's one more issue. If you have a field redefinition of the kind $\phi=\exp(a)$ or $\ln(b)$, then the non-derivative prefactors may change in various ways. ... David is a very smart and amusing guy. ... I don't understand how you could say that this mistake is a "different notation". It's like saying that $12\times 12=14$ in a different notation where I may omit the extra $4$ in the result.

Comment: Is it possible that the $\phi$ doesn't contribute to the action because of the standard boundary condtions?

Comment: @Motl, True. It would be an absurd notation. But Victor Stenger does the same thing. And I know I've seen it written that way other places too. Like Susskind's Lectures on youtube maybe. It's very strange. These are all great physicists.

Comment: BB1, I would have to see that they used those things but I can imagine Lenny omitting this factor. As long as he always implicitly added the factor while deriving the equations of motion or propagators, he could have survived his 40+-year stellar career rather easily with the opinion that the box phi is enough. And maybe there's one of the field redefinitions. I can show you many rather simple errors of this kind in various papers co-authored by Lenny. He's not the kind of a nitpicking rigorous guys caring about details.

Comment: Let me mention an example. Rigid Regge Rods, see: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0005015v1 - Then click the version v2 to see what happened what the paper. The error was in eqn 3.5 essentially due to a wrong treatment of the $i\epsilon$ term in the propagators. If I remember well, it was pointed out by Joe Polchinski rather quickly. I can also show you a wrong sign (of the potential term) in the main important equation, the Hamiltonian of Matrix theory, in the BFSS paper - never fixed - and many others. ;-)

Comment: Motl, lol. It is reassuring to know that the greats make mistakes too.  Is it a minor error or does it invalidate the result?

Comment: The part on the "stringy uncertainty principle" is very interesting. I've noticed that the papers written by (what I consider to be) the great physicists are easier to read than the ones written by lesser physicists. They weed out everything other than the essentials. This doesn't look that mathematically difficult considering what it's about.

Comment: Susskind is surely a kind of an intuitive "seer", so to say, and a no-nonsense guy from the working class. Did the errors affect the results? Yes, the Rigid Regge Rods paper was just completely wrong. So v1 was wrong, v2 was completely empty, and v3 was there again and it said the opposite conclusion than v1: string theory ultimately guarantees some locality. The sign error in the potential energy (they forgot that the commutator of two Hermitian operators is antiHermitian whose square is therefore negatively definite, so one has to switch the sign to get positively definie) was irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

OK just to be clear the lagrangian for a scalar field theory for scalar field is written as

$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi -\frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2  $

sometimes this is written as

$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} ( \partial^\mu \phi)^2 -\frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2  $

where

$( \partial^\mu \phi)^2 = \partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi$

the latter notation is a bit sloppy, but widespread and standard and usually clear from the context. Also watch out for stuff like

$ (F^{\mu \nu})^2 = F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu} $